# Synch JMS Consumer inside EJB doesn't work

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jms

I created a JMS consumer inside EJB but this doesn't work.

I created a queue in my application server glassfish, as in this screenshot:

[image]

Below, there is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package EJBData;

import Service.ResponceMessage;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSConsumer;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;

/**
 *
 * @author melix
 */
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class FrontEndConsumer {
    @Resource(lookup = "jms/__defaultConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    @Resource(lookup = "jms/QueueFrontEnd")
    private Queue queueFrontEnd;

    public ResponceMessage consume(){
        /*JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext();
        JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(queueFrontEnd);
        while (true) {
           Message m = consumer.receive(1000);
           if (m != null) {
              System.out.println("Mex!!!"); 
           }else {
               break;
           }
        }*/
        return null;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I remove "static" from both fields annotated with @Resource.

```
Severe:   ejb.stateless_ejbcreate_exception
Warning:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB AuctionFrontEnd, method: public java.lang.String EJBData.AuctionFrontEnd.generateJSONFromMap()
Warning:   javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2579)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1971)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1694.generateJSONFromMap(Unknown Source)
    at EJBExecutor.Reader.generateJSONFromMap(Reader.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor718.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor727.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1696.generateJSONFromMap(Unknown Source)
    at Auction$2.onAllDataRead(Auction.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.processAllDataRead(InputBuffer.java:548)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.access$600(InputBuffer.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl$2.run(InputBuffer.java:518)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1706)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:456)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at EJBData.AuctionFrontEnd.<init>(AuctionFrontEnd.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:104)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:190)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.produce(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl._createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1696)
    ... 49 more

Warning:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB Reader, method: public java.lang.String EJBExecutor.Reader.generateJSONFromMap()
Warning:   javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2579)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1971)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1694.generateJSONFromMap(Unknown Source)
    at EJBExecutor.Reader.generateJSONFromMap(Reader.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor718.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor727.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1696.generateJSONFromMap(Unknown Source)
    at Auction$2.onAllDataRead(Auction.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.processAllDataRead(InputBuffer.java:548)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.access$600(InputBuffer.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl$2.run(InputBuffer.java:518)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1706)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:456)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at EJBData.AuctionFrontEnd.<init>(AuctionFrontEnd.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractInstantiator.newInstance(AbstractInstantiator.java:28)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.produce(BasicInjectionTarget.java:104)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.produce(BeanInjectionTarget.java:190)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ejb.SessionBeanInjectionTarget.produce(SessionBeanInjectionTarget.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl._createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.createJCDIInjectionContext(JCDIServiceImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.createEjbInstanceAndContext(BaseContainer.java:1696)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: I tried this:    @Resource(mappedName = "QueueFrontEnd")
                    private Queue queueFrontEnd;
                    @Inject
   @JMSConnectionFactory("java:comp/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory")
    private JMSContext context; but doesn't work!!! The error is caused by the lines with annotation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason can be obtained from logs actually - please remove "static" from both fields annotated with @Resource.

Comment: I removed static from both fields annotated with @Resource and now i have another error logs. I reported the new log in the original post.

Comment: Again - the clue is in the log :) - you have NPE in AuctionFrontEnd.java:225. Please debug it and then setting up EJB should go futher.